# write and read configuration data using File operation in Android

Tags: android, file-io

In my application there are some configuration data, such as ipaddress, portno, title and etc.  I want to keep these data in phone privately.  I decided to write data in below format

```
IPAddress=127.0.0.1
Port=1234
Title=MyNewApplication
```

i am confused with file streams.  I also want to update values without using a temperory file.  Please provide a solution to this.

I tried with below code

```
public class Mtx {

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

public static void ConfWrite(String type, String value) {
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(null);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("IPAddress", "127.0.0.1");
    editor.putInt("port", 1234);
    editor.putString("Title", "MyNewApplication");

    // Commit the edits!
    editor.commit();
}

public static void ConfRead( String type, String value ) {

        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(null);
        String ipAddress = settings.getString("IPAddress", "");
        int port = settings.getInt("port", 0);
        String title = settings.getString("Title", "");

        Log.e("", title);
}
}
```

Comment: I use this and it works by passing name of repository: SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(REPOSITORY_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SharedPreferences` instead.
Simple to use.

Details can be found here.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
   super.onCreate(state);
   . . .

   // Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   String ipAddress = settings.getString("IPAddress", "");
   int port = settings.getInt("port", 0);
   int title = settings.getString("Title", "");
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();

  // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
  // All objects are from android.context.Context
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putString("IPAddress", "127.0.0.1");
  editor.putInt("port", 1234);
  editor.putString("Title", "MyNewApplication");

  // Commit the edits!
  editor.commit();
}}
```

Comment: while running the applicatin it got an error message \"The method getSharedPreferences(String, int) is undefined for the type\". How can i correct it ?