# How to read a config file in SD card with SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9172615/2653579

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
   super.onCreate(state);
   . . .

   // Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   String ipAddress = settings.getString("IPAddress", "");
   int port = settings.getInt("port", 0);
   int title = settings.getString("Title", "");
}
```

I found that code for read values from a config file and i cant make it to read a file from the SD Card. I tried this way:

```
static File GPSCfgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Config/GPSLogService.cfg");
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = String.valueOf(GPSCfgFile);
```

When i starting my service, it stops unexpectedly. This was in the logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
GPSLogService.cfg.xml contains a path separator
```

How can i make it to read that file from the SD card?

Comment: I don't think you can read a file with `String.valueOf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a file using the method `String.valueOf()` :
If you are using a XML config file you can have a look this links to know how you can do it:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html#instantiate

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidXML/article.html

If you are using a plain text file you can take a look here:

[How can I read a text file from the SD card in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902689/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-from-the-sd-card-in-android)

While you are reading your config file, you must save each value on an individual `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ConstantsUtils.PREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("IPAddress", "Tag value" );
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you. How can i turn this SharedPreferences to a long and use it in an other method? I'm stuck here.

Comment: You can use the preferences which you saved as you wrote in your question SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   String ipAddress = settings.getString("IPAddress", "");